# Makefile is not working? 'Nothing to be done for 'makefile'

Tags: c, makefile

So i am receiving the error 'Nothing to be done for makefile'
I have the following in my makefile

```
hellomake: A2Q1 A2Q2

A2Q1: A2Q1.c 
        gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -o A2Q1 A2Q1.c

A2Q2: A2Q2.c 
        gcc -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -o A2Q2 A2Q2.c
```

Comment: Try `make hellomake`

Comment: Is that really your whole makefile? Or do you have a line at the beginning of your makefile that says `makefile:`?

Comment: what is the command you are invoking?

Comment: If you say `make makefile` instead of `make -f makefile` or just `make`, then you will probably get an error like what you suggest you're getting.  We need to know that your file really is named `makefile`, and exactly how you're running the `make` command.

Answer (score 1):

The way make works is as follows. When you give the command `make`, the default target in the file *makefile* or *Makefile* is executed. In your case, the default target is the first one you defined, *hellomake*. `make A2Q1` executes the actions under the target *A2Q1*. And `make -f mymakefile` executes the default target in the file *mymakefile*.

So you probably are giving the command `make makefile`, which makes *make* to try to execute the target *makefile*. And because you don't specify that target and the file already exist, that is the message that you get.